# Make 'OR' in 'EQUAL' in JS

Tags: javascript

Are it's possible to make 'equals' like this

```
if(index==1|12|23|34|45|56){
    //do
}
```

Or it's actually must use this:

```
if(index==1|index==12|index==23|index==34|index==45|index==56){
    // do
}
```

But how if its many index there?

Please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) you can test on an object (but this doesn't work on objects and types):

```
var obj = {1: 1, 12: 1, 23: 1, 34: 1, 45: 1, 56: 1};

if( obj[index] ) {
    // do
}
```

Or make a string: ( Again only works on string/number )

```
var s = "," + [1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56].join(",") + ",";

if ( s.indexOf( "," + index + "," ) !== -1 ) {
    // do
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use an array and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if ([1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56].indexOf(index) != -1) {
  // do your thing
}
```

If your browser does not support `indexOf`, there's an implementation in the above link.

Comment: Keep in mind, that `Array.indexOf` is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @phant0m: Indeed, if that's the case, you can always use a polyfill such as the one provided in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, but with a helper function, you can do something close:

```
if(inArray(index, [1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56])) { ... }
```

Here is the implementation:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: for me this is the cleanest way to do a inArray. of course in array functions are slow with great amounts of items. therefor there are indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Combine them into a single string and indexOf will automatically coerce the types!  This also gets around the lack of Array.indexOf support in some older browsers!

```
if ("123456".indexOf(1)) {
// ...
}
```

Now, you might ask yourself...

> "Self, what if I wanted to combine something more complicated, like
>   all the US States?"*

Well that's easy!  First list out all the states:

```
al ak az ar ca co ct de fl ga hi id il in ia ks ky 
la me md ma mi mn ms mo mt ne nv nh nj nm ny nc nd 
oh ok or pa ri sc sd tn tx ut vt va wa wv wi wy
```

Then combine the word groups to reduce the code size by joining the starting letter of one word with the ending letter of another.  Repeat until you can't combine them anymore.

```
if ("fl gal morilar mnvtnmt minde msd me ma mdct ncokscaky ny nh nj ne ohia pa utx wva waz wid wy vi pr".indexOf("ny")) {
   alert("New York!");
}
```

Warning: doing this may get you labeled as a nutcase.